# org.dbunit.dataset.NoSuchTableException, but table exists

Tags: java, sql, junit, h2, dbunit

H2 1.4.191.
DbUnit 2.5.1. 
How this can be fixed?
Code and results for 3 cases:

```
org.dbunit.dataset.NoSuchTableException: category
org.dbunit.dataset.NoSuchTableException: Category
org.dbunit.dataset.NoSuchTableException: CATEGORY
//
<dataset>
<Category categoryId="9223372036854775806"
      categoryName="NAME"
      categoryParentId="9223372036854775805"/>   
</dataset>
//
CREATE TABLE Category (
  categoryId       INT          AUTO_INCREMENT,
  categoryName     VARCHAR      NOT NULL,
  categoryParentId INT          NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (categoryId)
)
//Check - tried to recreate
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "CATEGORY" already exists;
```

Comment: Are you using a DTD to load the XML files?  If so can you post that too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes when you are using dbunit you need to define the schema from which you are trying to use the table, probably you could try to add

```
<dataset>
<schema.Category categoryId="9223372036854775806"
      categoryName="NAME"
      categoryParentId="9223372036854775805"/>   
</dataset>
```

If not check the datasource that you are using, probably you are not pointing to the correct database or schema.

For dbunit we have some [properties](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/properties.html) consider using the `Qualified table names` property as follows.

```
DatabaseConfig dBConfig = dBConn.getConfig(); // dBConn is a IDatabaseConnection
dBConfig.setProperty(DatabaseConfig.FEATURE_QUALIFIED_TABLE_NAMES, true);
```

Comment: Thank you! But how it should be specified? I am using default "test" schema. "<test.Category" did not helped.

Comment: I added the config in my response

Comment: Thank you very much again! I've done "result.getConfig().setProperty(DatabaseConfig.FEATURE_QUALIFIED_TABLE_NAMES, true);" as you told, but problem still exists: org.dbunit.dataset.NoSuchTableException: test.Category

Comment: Try to do all in uppercase, there is a case insensitive property as well