# org.dbunit.dataset.NoSuchTableException: UserTest

Tags: java, maven, junit, dbunit

I have found some example of how to use dbunit [here, from the junitbook2 example](https://kent.dl.sourceforge.net/project/junitbook/junitbook2/)

I have tried and It works, so I have try to use It in my project; my project is maven based, and to use the database I use a reference to an external jar that create my table's bean with "ant run".
So in my maven project I have create 1 Interface (UserDao) in my src/main/java + other class in src/test/java like the example in the book.

UserDao interface :

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import com.mydb.UserTest;
public interface UserDao {

  /**
   * Insert an user in the database.
   * 
   * @param user user to be inserted
   * @return if id the inserted user
   */
  long addUser( UserTest user ) throws SQLException;
  UserTest getUserById( long id ) throws SQLException;
}
```

AbstractDbUnitTestCase:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

import org.dbunit.dataset.IDataSet;
import org.dbunit.dataset.ReplacementDataSet;
import org.dbunit.dataset.xml.FlatXmlDataSet;
import org.dbunit.ext.hsqldb.HsqldbConnection;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;

public abstract class AbstractDbUnitTestCase {

  protected static UserDaoJdbcImpl dao = new UserDaoJdbcImpl();
  protected static Connection connection;
  protected static HsqldbConnection dbunitConnection;

  @BeforeClass
  public static void setupDatabase() throws Exception {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://mydb/mydb","user","password");
    if (connection != null) 
        System.out.println("Connected to the database");
    dbunitConnection = new HsqldbConnection(connection,null);
    dao.setConnection(connection);
  }

  @AfterClass
  public static void closeDatabase() throws Exception {
    if ( dbunitConnection != null ) {
      dbunitConnection.close();
      dbunitConnection = null;
    }
  }

  public static IDataSet getDataSet(String name) throws Exception {
    InputStream inputStream = AbstractDbUnitTestCase.class.getResourceAsStream(name);
    assertNotNull("file " + name + " not found in classpath", inputStream );
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    FlatXmlDataSet dataset = new FlatXmlDataSet(reader);
    return dataset;
  }

  public static IDataSet getReplacedDataSet(String name, long id) throws Exception {
    IDataSet originalDataSet = getDataSet(name);
    return getReplacedDataSet(originalDataSet, id);
  }

  public static IDataSet getReplacedDataSet(IDataSet originalDataSet, long id) throws Exception {
    ReplacementDataSet replacementDataSet = new ReplacementDataSet(originalDataSet);
    replacementDataSet.addReplacementObject("[ID]", id);
    replacementDataSet.addReplacementObject("[NULL]", null);
    return replacementDataSet;
  }

}
```

UserDaoJdbcImplTest --> where is the test

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static com.test.EntitiesHelper.*;


import org.dbunit.Assertion;
import org.dbunit.dataset.IDataSet;
import org.dbunit.operation.DatabaseOperation;
import org.junit.Ignore;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.mydb.UserTest;

public class UserDaoJdbcImplTest extends AbstractDbUnitTestCase {

  @Test
  public void testGetUserById() throws Exception {
    IDataSet setupDataSet = getDataSet("/user.xml");
    DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT.execute(dbunitConnection, setupDataSet);
    UserProvaTest user = dao.getUserById(1);
    assertNotNull( user);
    assertEquals( "Jeffrey", user.getFirstName() );
    assertEquals( "Lebowsky", user.getLastName() );
    assertEquals( "ElDuderino", user.getUsername() );
  }

  @Test @Ignore("fails if run together with others")
  public void testAddUser() throws Exception {
    UserProvaTest user = newUser();
    long id = dao.addUser(user);
    assertTrue(id>0);
    IDataSet expectedDataSet = getDataSet("/user.xml");
    IDataSet actualDataSet = dbunitConnection.createDataSet();
    Assertion.assertEquals( expectedDataSet, actualDataSet );
  }

  @Test
  public void testAddUseIgnoringId() throws Exception {
    IDataSet setupDataSet = getDataSet("/user.xml");
    DatabaseOperation.DELETE_ALL.execute(dbunitConnection, setupDataSet);
    UserProvaTest user = newUser();
    long id = dao.addUser(user);
    assertTrue(id>0);
    IDataSet expectedDataSet = getDataSet("/user.xml");
    IDataSet actualDataSet = dbunitConnection.createDataSet();
    Assertion.assertEqualsIgnoreCols( expectedDataSet, actualDataSet, "users", new String[] { "id" } );
  }

  @Test
  public void testGetUserByIdReplacingIds() throws Exception {
    long id = 42;
    IDataSet setupDataset = getReplacedDataSet("/user-token.xml", id );
    DatabaseOperation.INSERT.execute(dbunitConnection, setupDataset);
    UserProvaTest user = dao.getUserById(id);
    assertUser(user);
  }

  @Test
  public void testAddUserReplacingIds() throws Exception {
    IDataSet setupDataSet = getDataSet("/user-token.xml");
    DatabaseOperation.DELETE_ALL.execute(dbunitConnection, setupDataSet);
    UserProvaTest user = newUser();
    long id = dao.addUser(user);
    assertTrue(id>0);
    IDataSet expectedDataSet = getReplacedDataSet(setupDataSet, id );
    IDataSet actualDataSet = dbunitConnection.createDataSet();
    Assertion.assertEquals( expectedDataSet, actualDataSet );
  }

}
```

My Bean UserTest is created in this way :

```
@Entity (name="mydb_UserTest")@Table(name="UserTest"
    ,catalog="mydb" )
```

and the user.xml file :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<dataset>
  <mydb_UserTest id="1" username="ElDuderino" first_name="Jeffrey" last_name="Lebowsky" />
</dataset>
```

But when I tried to execute the test I have this error:

> testGetUserById(com.test.UserDaoJdbcImplTest)  Time elapsed: 0.176 sec
>   <<< ERROR! org.dbunit.dataset.NoSuchTableException: UserTest

I have see that :

1. the connection to the database is correct
2. but no matter what I wrote into the user.xml file, for example
   User1111Test instead of UserTest, the error is the same(like org.dbunit.dataset.NoSuchTableException: User1111Test); I have also try to use schema.UserTest, that is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35777580/org-dbunit-dataset-nosuchtableexception-but-table-exists) but the error is the same NoSuchTableException: schema.UserTest.
3. The error is in this point :

   > DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT.execute(dbunitConnection,
   >   setupDataSet);

I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Finally, I got the solution...*

I changed my table name in DB from `UserTest` to `USERTEST`, and I use this `user.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<dataset>
  <USERTEST id="1" username="ElDuderino" first_name="Jeffrey" last_name="Lebowsky" />
</dataset>
```

I think, in my case, there is no alternatives because the 2 properties:

```java
config.setProperty(DatabaseConfig.FEATURE_QUALIFIED_TABLE_NAMES, true);
config.setProperty(DatabaseConfig.FEATURE_CASE_SENSITIVE_TABLE_NAMES, true);
```

Return this info, so they don't work:

```
[main] INFO org.dbunit.database.DatabaseConfig - Unknown property 'http://www.dbunit.org/features/qualifiedTableNames'. Cannot validate the type of the object to be set. Please notify a developer to update the list of properties.  
[main] INFO org.dbunit.database.DatabaseConfig - Unknown property 'http://www.dbunit.org/features/caseSensitiveTableNames'. Cannot validate the type of the object to be set. Please notify a developer to update the list of properties.
```

UPDATE:
The solution to avoid the info/error of `FEATURE_QUALIFIED_TABLE_NAMES` is to use

dbunitConnection.getConfig().setFeature(DatabaseConfig.FEATURE_QUALIFIED_TABLE_NAMES, true);
    dbunitConnection.getConfig().setFeature(DatabaseConfig.FEATURE_CASE_SENSITIVE_TABLE_NAMES, true);

instead of `setProperty`; and change `HsqldbConnection dbunitConnection` to  `MySqlConnection dbunitConnection`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `FEATURE_QUALIFIED_TABLE_NAMES` property:

```
DatabaseConfig config = dBConn.getConfig();
config.setProperty(DatabaseConfig.FEATURE_QUALIFIED_TABLE_NAMES, true);
```

Place it in your setupDatabase method.

In your `dataset` you must add the schema name:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<dataset>
 <SCHEMA.USERTEST ID="1" USERNAME="ELDUDERINO" FIRST_NAME="JEFFREY" LAST_NAME="LEBOWSKY" />
</dataset>
```

Note the dataset in uppercase.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the method setUpDatabaseConfig is not present in my project, do you mean setupDatabase in my AbstractDbUnitTestCase? Can you be more specific? And my table name is UserTest, there is no problem with the uppercase? thanks

Comment: I´ve edited the answer. My table names are in lowercase and I had issue specifying dataset in lowercase too.

Comment: I have change my code with yours, I put the code you suggest at the end of my setupDatabase() method and now there is this error before the usual error: 
10 [main] INFO org.dbunit.database.DatabaseConfig - Unknown property 'http://www.dbunit.org/features/qualifiedTableNames'. Cannot validate the type of the object to be set. Please notify a developer to update the list of properties.
org.dbunit.dataset.NoSuchTableException: SCHEMA.USERTEST

Comment: Sorry I have omitted to write that my beans are created in this way: 
@Entity
(name="mydb_UserTest")@Table(name="UserTest"
    ,catalog="mydb"
) So I use MYDB_USERTEST in dataset

Answer (score 0):

Based on this info:

```
@Entity (name="mydb_UserTest")@Table(name="UserTest"
    ,catalog="mydb" )
```

the correct dbUnit file table name is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<dataset>
  <mydb.UserTest id="1" username="ElDuderino" first_name="Jeffrey" last_name="Lebowsky" />
</dataset>
```

Or without the schema name if it's the default schema for the database user (usually when the schema name matches the user name):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<dataset>
  <UserTest id="1" username="ElDuderino" first_name="Jeffrey" last_name="Lebowsky" />
</dataset>
```